# Why am I grounding my HV probe to mains to read a secondary (different) voltage in that circuit?

Tags: high-voltage, multimeter, voltage-measurement

In this scenario I'm measuring output of a 4 wire 5kV transformer: line voltage on primary, two HV wires on secondary. For any normal multimeter reading, if I want to measure any single component on a circuit, I'm putting my leads on that individual component. For instance, if I'm measuring a 5V piezoelectric sensor on a car, I'm not putting my meter probes on battery negative and 5V positive; I'll get wacky readings. So why does my HV probe require me to ground on 110, and touch the lead to the 5kV secondary? Shouldn't my probe (ground AND hot points of contact ) be connected only to the secondary side?

Edit: [image]
Probe ground to secondary: incorrect reading.
Probe ground to primary: correct reading of 5kV

To clarify my question: regular voltage measurements, as I'm familiar with, involve reading voltage AT the individual component in a circuit, because those components on that circuit many times operate under voltages different than the input voltage that's powering the device. Voltage readings on the device means I'm attaching both Com and V to the device.

Yet the proper way to measure the output voltage of this transformer was to take that reading from two completely different parts of a circuit, one a 5kV, and one a 110. If voltage reading comes from the difference in potential, wouldn't this yield 4,000 - 110, which would be 3,890V?

*Resistance measurements (for OP to complete).*

```
    Terminals            Resistance
    ------------------------------
    Black to white       Ω
    Black to HT1         Ω
    Black to HT2*        Ω
    Black to frame**     Ω
    HT1 to HT2*          Ω
    HT1 to frame         Ω

    * To be found. Not visible in photos.
    ** Frame or wire attached to frame by ring terminal.
```

Comment: Please draw a schematic.

Comment: (1) "*...  why is my HV probe telling me ...*" What does this mean? Do you mean the probe's user manual tells you? If so, can you link to the manual? (2) "*Shouldn't my ground AND power on the secondary side?*" Do you mean **probe** instead of "power"? Can you [edit] to clarify. Again a schematic would clarify. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Probably for safety. If you have an HV probe. you need the ground side to go to a safe ground such that the probe output is always a safe voltage. Show a schematic of what you want to measure. It sounds like you want to measure the output of a floating HV secondary. If so, ground one side of the secondary as well.

Comment: I have a standard Fluke probe that connects to the ground and power inputs on any standard meter, and it also has a ground clip. I was told that the way to use this probe was by clipping the ground clip to "mains."  The transformer is about as simple and basic as they come. 2 wires to the primary coil (110v) and 2 wires from the secondary coil, to power the device. When my probe was connected at both points (grounding lead and tip of probe) to both secondary wires, I got bad readings. When I attached ground lead to primary, and touched probe to secondary, I got accurate reading.

Comment: @JaredCravens to the safety ground of the mains, surely! Edit into your question a link to the manual, or add a picture of the part of the manual that tells you to clip the probe ground to the mains. AND POST A SCHEMATIC OF WHAT YOU'RE TRYING TO MEASURE. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar

Comment: Jared, you can see your setup. We can't. There were a number of errors in your original post which caused confusion (which you haven't acknowledged in your comment above) and there are still references to  a piezoelectric sensor in a car which has nothing to do with the question. We're looking for context to help you. Measuring voltage across an isolation transformer doesn't make sense so your readers would like to know why you are doing it. "I'll get wacky readings" is not a good technical description. What readings do you get? Why not include a photo of the setup? Over to you.

Comment: @JaredCravens Thanks for the picture. What is the 'incorrect reading'? What makes you think it's incorrect? I notice the secondary ground is also the core. Is the core grounded to mains safety ground? If not, why not?

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed the scenario was pretty clear, but perhaps I did a poor job of explaining it. The automotive sensor was an example of measuring voltage at an isolated point or device (5V) instead of taking part of the reading from a common (12v ground) when on a circuit that involves different voltages. Just an example.

Comment: @Neil_UK When I measured with ground clip to primary, I got a simple, clean 5kV reading. When I measured with ground clip to secondary, my readings were all over the place. It would fluctuate up and down while sitting there (I was not holding the probe, so no human movement) with readings of 1-2kV, and when I'd pick up the probe and point it far away, i was still getting voltage readings on my meter. So I'd hardly even call this a reading at all. Could have just been my meter not at total 0 and not seeing an actual input voltage.

Comment: @Neil_UK Core is not grounded to mains, core only serves as ground side to the secondary voltage. Wouldn't core being the ground to secondary circuit as well as primary voltage be a short?

Comment: @JaredCravens Transformer core grounded to mains safety ground is usually required for mains operated things. This is usually achieved by the transformer being mounted in an earthed chassis with conducting fasteners. The secondary can be floating, or grounded on one side, depending on how you want to use the secondary. I've just read Transistor's answer - you MUST be able to get a resistance reading (aka continuity)(with power off of course) between the two points you're trying to measure HV on, otherwise you'll read rubbish. I'd expect something in the 100s to kohms range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photos you've added reveal that one of your "secondary" connections is the transformer laminations. You need to check for continuity between the HT wire and the frame. Take a resistance measurment and see if you can see a secondary connection to the frame.

There is a possibility that the transformer is an auto-transformer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgIYgF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Autotransformer configuration. Note that in this configuration there is no internal connection to the transformer frame.*

You should be able to find which wire is common using resistance measurement techniques.

If the configuration is as shown in Figure 1 then it should be clear that measuring between HT and frame will just give you a reading of capacitive coupling. Correct meter common reference should be to the common terminal on the transformer.

---

I don't see any fuse in your test setup. This is bad practice and may bite you some day.

Comment: No continuity between HT wire and frame. If there was, this would be a short, correct? The bottom line here is that the component (neon gas tube) is fed it's 5kV by these two wires. Voltage is two wires to move electrons. So why can I not measure it by sticking with both of my secondary wires? The secondary common, regardless of how it's wired, is still half of the 5,000V worth of moving electrons, just as the hot HT wire.

Comment: If there is no continuity between HT and frame then you can't expect to measure a voltage between them. "*... this would be a short, correct?*" No, it would be the coil resistance. Forget about "electrons". Just think of current. In the neon gas both electrons and positive ions flow in opposite directions. I can't make any sense of your last sentence. You need to find out where the other end of the HT winding is terminated. A better photo would help. Try to show the secondary coil terminations.

Comment: Also, check for continuity between the primary and the HT lead.

Comment: I was wrong, I have 10.6kΩ between both secondaries. I can't understand any event in which measuring voltage at the two wires that feed a load will not yield a measurement of the voltage going to the load. Maybe my theory of operation/fundamentals are just wrong, and you're assuming I know something which I've failed to understand. A voltage reading as I've always understood is made by reading from the power and ground that directly feed a load, but somehow I'm supposed to get that reading from two completely different voltages, A 5kV hot and a 110V negative that doesn't feed my load.

Comment: "*I have 10.6kΩ between both secondaries.*" There is only one secondary. Do you mean between the HT wire from the coil and the wire on the transformer chassis? (You need to be precise.) If so 10.6 kΩ seems high. Note that you haven't reported on checking for a connection between primary and HT lead.

Comment: @JaredCravens - you have 5 connections to conductors - the core, 2 primary wires, and 2 secondary wires. Set up a matrix and record the resistance between all 5 terminals in pairs, it won't take long, and will potentially save a lot of confusion. Edit the resulting table into your question.

Comment: The transformer supplies 5kV, the secondary voltage, to the load via 2 wires on the secondary side. You cannot supply current to something with only 1 wire. So I'm calling my 5kV wires supplying the secondary voltage "secondary wires." I'd love to keep ohming this transformer out for you, but this seems to be a tangent. None of that matters unless you can explain to me why measuring voltage at the two wires that feed ANY load from ANY voltage source does not yield a measurement of the voltage going to the load. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Just to clarify: Which picture are you guys saying is the correct way to read secondary voltage? Left or Right? Because Right seems wrong, but that's giving me a correct measurement, and that's how I was taught to use a HV probe.

Comment: I have already explained a possible reason for your readings in my answer. Your rudeness to those trying to help you is not doing you any favours and is certainly putting me off trying to help you. The information you have been asked is the **basic requirements** to determine the internal wiring of your transformer and should have been in the question in the first instance. "*So I'm calling my 5kV wires supplying the secondary voltage "secondary wires."*" And I'm pointing out to you that that is incorrect terminology which generates confusion.

Comment: I apologize for my tone, I certainly don't want to annoy the people I'm seeking help from. I'm not an electrical engineer.

Comment: Right. Well why are you objecting to taking the measurements? It is the first level of investigation and is very basic to analysing the problem. We've given you really simple faultfinding instructions so ... [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: I absolutely will get these measurements for you. My hesitancy has been due to my worry that you're going in a different direction while I still don't understand the very core question I came here with. Is it possible that the voltage at two wires from any voltage source that feed any load (barring some wild, atypical scenario) will not yield a measurement of the voltage going to the load? And are we on the same page that Left is the incorrect way to measure, and Right is correct ?

Comment: I don't see a fault or a problem. I'm asking which is the proper method, and why.

Comment: We can't know which is the proper method until we know for sure what way the transformer is wired. My Figure 1 shows a three-wire connection with a separate earth lead. I'm not convinced that the frame terminal is connected to the transformer secondary.

Comment: But both HT wires are still responsible for carrying/supplying the secondary voltage, and isn't this how you take voltage measurements? By reading from the 2 wires which supply your load? I already verified that the Right picture gave me the correct measurements, what I'm wondering is why. It doesn't seem right that the way to measure voltage on circuit B can be done by splitting your test leads between circuit B and circuit Z, which are operating under different voltages.

Comment: @JaredCravens You want to know **why** the RH setup gives stable readings and the LH one doesn't? Because you're making an assumption that isn't correct. Which one we don't know yet. 40 years of engineering has taught me, and Transistor, that 'weird' results happen when you make wrong guesses about the component in front of you. Find out what the component is, stop guessing, that is the **proper method**. Your question is on the same level as 'I've arrived in London, do I turn left or right to get to Oxford? What direction am I facing? I don't see how that matters, I'm **IN** London damnit!'

Comment: @JaredCravens, thank you for accepting my answer but is it correct? Is the device configured as an autotransformer? Is there conductivity between the primary and secondary?

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**: The test configuration seems invalid, leading to unexpected measurements.

The topic of the transformer frame (core) not being grounded was raised in earlier [comments](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/579617/why-am-i-grounding-my-hv-probe-to-mains-to-read-a-secondary-different-voltage#comment1516429_579617), and that is likely to be the cause of your incorrect measurements.

---

**Details**: What you have there is a [neon sign transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon-sign_transformer) (NST). The label seems to show that it's a "Franceformer 5020 SE", rated output 5000 V and 20 mA. (I would be interested what the caution label says on the top.)

I could not find that as a current model on the Franceformer (now part of SFEG) [website](http://www.franceformer.com/). The closest I could find (visually and specifications) now listed on their website, is the [3020 SEG-U](https://www.sfeg.com/product/3020-seg-u/) ([datasheet](https://www.sfeg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/SEG-U_Install.pdf)).

I'll start with a warning and disclaimer: The voltage at both the mains input and HV output of the transformer (5 kV in your case) can cause death, injury, fire or other damage. Anything you do is totally your responsibility.

I have some experience with NSTs from long ago. To cut straight to the point, you ask in a [comment on another answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/579617/why-am-i-grounding-my-hv-probe-to-mains-to-read-a-secondary-different-voltage#comment1516597_579677):

> Which picture are you [...] saying is the correct way to read secondary voltage? Left or Right? Because Right seems wrong, but that's giving me a correct measurement, and that's how I was taught to use a HV probe.

The response is: Neither of them is completely correct, and that is why your results are confusing - your test configuration is invalid.

Your NST has only one HV output wire (this type of NST is variously called unbalanced / single-ended / single-end grounded / one-end referenced / one-end grounded). That HV output wire is where your photos show the HV test probe measurement "point", so that is correct.

However on this type of NST, the output voltage is referenced to ground (as you are trying to measure in your left photo) **but you have not grounded the transformer**. The other end of the HV secondary is internally connected to the transformer frame (core). That is where your other output wire is already connected, as we see in your photos, and the frame should be grounded - usually via the mains earth wire.

See below (from [Questions and Answers on Neon Transformers)](http://www.electricsignrepairtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Questions-and-Answers-on-Neon-Tranformers.pdf):

[image: one end grounded neon sign transformer]

You seem to be measuring the correct voltage in your right-hand photo because the "common" (a.k.a. ground) clip for your HV measurement probe is connected to the transformer mains neutral input, which should be within a few volts of ground. So by luck, your measurement seems to work. But that configuration, without the transformer being grounded, is still invalid and unsafe.

You need to:

- Make the mains connections safe. Your photos seem to show uninsulated twisted wire connections, from the transformer's mains input wires to another cable with a mains plug. These connections could becomes loose, unintentionally touch each other or other objects etc. with dangerous consequences.
- I was taught that the mains input to those neon sign transformers is AC polarity-sensitive i.e. the transformer black input wire must go to the mains hot (live), and the transformer white input wire must go to the mains neutral. I don't know the reason for this, but the fact that these transformers use different colors for the mains input wires (white and black), rather than two wires of the same color, is consistent with polarity being important.
- The transformer's body itself must be connected to mains ground. Failure to do so can cause the transformer body to reach a dangerous voltage by capacitive coupling, as well as incorrect output voltage.
- The image below (from [signindustry.com - Essential Tools of the Trade](http://www.signindustry.com/electric/articles/2003-05-08-EssentialToolsofTrade.php3)), shows the correct test configuration, similar to your right-hand photo - *except* your transformer has only 1 HV output wire, not the 2 HV outputs shown in that image (that's a different type of NST). So the other end of the neon sign would be grounded via the wire connected to your transformer's frame, if using your type of transformer:

  [image: neon sign test wiring configuration]

  Then you should be able to measure 5 kV between the HV output wire and the grounded transformer frame.

Comment: Good answer, Sam. Do you reckon the OP's secondary is referenced to the frame or not? I can only explain the readings if it's an auto-transformer isolated from ground and grounding the frame would then give a neutral reference through the mains-neutral link at the supply. I was unable to find a datasheet for it either.